# How to add all positive integers and get their average

Tags: c++

Im a beginner at c++ and Im having a hard time, Im still a student, our professor ask us to input numbers(must input positive and negative) and print the sum of the positive integers and their average, example:

```
How many input? 5
input # 1 : 5
input # 2 : 3
input # 3 : -2
input # 4 : -4
input # 5 : 6
```

so the expected output is to print the positive integers, in this case is 5, 3, and 6

Comment: Please could you share what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly simple problem (almost everything isif one's basics are clear). The [below](https://onlinegdb.com/GYx5lEJFp) program shows how you can do this. I have added some comments so that you can get an idea about what is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int numberOfInputs = 0;
    std::cout<<"How many inputs?"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>numberOfInputs;//take input into numberOfInputs
    
    std::vector<int> vectorOfInputs(numberOfInputs);//this vector(container) will contain all the inputs(both positive and negative)
    
    //this will contain the sum of all positive numbers 
    int sum = 0;
    
    //this will count how many numbers entered by user are positive
    int countPositive = 0;
    
    //use for loop or any other loop populate the vector by user input
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<<"input#"<<i+1<<":";
        std::cin >> vectorOfInputs.at(i);
        //if the number is positive increase sum
        if(vectorOfInputs.at(i) >0)
        {
            sum += vectorOfInputs.at(i);
            ++countPositive;
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    //print all the positive numbers 
    for(int elem: vectorOfInputs)
    {
        if(elem>0)
        {
            std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    
    //print the sum and average 
    std::cout<<"the sum of all the above positive numbers is: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"the average of all the above positive numbers is: "<<(static_cast<double>(sum))/countPositive<<std::endl;//static_cast is used to get the result as double instead of int
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

---------------- Edit ----------------

I completely missed that you need to output the positive integers as well.. In that case, take a look at `std::vector` where you would add these integers, and then you would iterate through them using a `for` loop again. Or, you could also print them out right away..

Since this is apparently your homework, I will try to avoid a code solution.

**Number of inputs**

This should be pretty straight-forward - using `std::cin` should be more than sufficient to ask for number of inputs (look at `std::cout` to printing the leading text 'How many inputs?') - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin . This input will be `n`.

**Getting inputs**

You will still make the use if `std::cin`, and a loop. I would say a `for` loop will probably be the easiest - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for . The goal is to do `n` iterations, and in every iteration, you can check if the input is either positive, or negative. Handle each case - either disregard it, or count the value.

**Average**

That should be the last and easiest part - you already have sum of your positive numbers, you know how many positive numbers you have (which happens in step 2) - basic arithmetics.